# How to bypass "Macros have been disabled" message and have macros run Workbook_Activate?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that formats/resizes the screen when the workbook/worksheet is activated.

The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  Dim SaveSelection As Object
  Set SaveSelection = Selection
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Range("A1:T50").Select
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
  Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
  Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
  ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
  ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
  ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
   Range("A1:T50").Select
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
  On Error GoTo ExitPoint
  SaveSelection.Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ExitPoint:
End Sub
```

The problem here is that when the user first opens the workbook, they get this Security Warning message "Macros have been disabled", so the macro does not run when the user first opens the workbook because the message appears.

Does anyone know of a workaround to this?

Comment: Social engineering?

Comment: Who is the intended user, and what's their relationship to you ?  Same company, or different/random ?

Comment: install a rootkit?

Comment: Same company. Co-workers

Answer (score 3):

This can often be resolved by including the workbook's folder path in their [Trusted Locations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-f5151879-25ea-4998-80a5-4208b3540a62).

Answer (score 2):

As sigil pointed out adding the file's folder location to the Trusted Locations will prevent the `Enable Content` and `Enable Macros` dialog boxes from appearing.

Alternately, you could create a VBScript file to open the workbook.

- Paste this could into NotePad
- Adjust the FILE_NAME constant
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Click [Save as type]
- Select All Files (*.*)
- Save the file with `.vbs` as it's extension

---

```
Const FILE_NAME = "C:\Excel FIles\Hello World.xlsm"
Dim oExcel
On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If TypeName(oExcel) = "Empty" Then Set oExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.Workbooks.Open FILE_NAME
```